# Remove White-space and New line from Arabic text using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I want to delete all whitespaces and newlines from Arabic string  using visual basic, I used to replace  vbCr,vbLf with an empty string but it doesn't work with me

my text:

> وصول مجموعة ملابس مميزة خاصة بعيد الفطر السعيد من سترمس .
>
> الخليل-الحرس"

message length should be 69 as calculated in Microsoft word  but when using vb is equal 71 char

```
      msg = Trim(msg)
      msg = msg.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "") 
      msg = msg.Replace(Environment.NewLine, String.Empty)
    Console.WriteLine(MyNewString.Length & msg.length)
```

I want the length of this message to be 69, how to remove the newlines from my text

Comment: I copied the text from your question and used your code and got 69 for the length. Please would you try copying the above text and using it with your code, in case something got lost in the question.

Comment: *delete all whitespaces* - your code makes no attempt to delete anything other than CR and LF. What do you mean when you say "whitespace" ?

Comment: What's the point in explicitly replacing carriage returns and line feeds and then also replacing line breaks? Line breaks are system dependent but they b=never contain anything other than carriage returns and line feeds so there can't possibly be any line breaks at that point.